# Inserting the value in data frame into the codes in R

Tags: r, design-patterns, replace

I have the names of the 1000 people in "name" data frame

```
df=c("John","Smith", .... "Machine")
```

I have the 1000 data frames for each person. (e.g., a1~a1000) 
And, I have the following codes.

```
a1$name="XXXX"
a2$name="XXXX" ...
a1000$name="XXXX"
```

I would like to replace "XXXX" in the above codes with the values in name data frame. Output codes would look like this.

```
a1$name="John"
a2$name="Smith" ...
a1000$name="Machine"
```

Comment: Do you have the possibility to store the data.frames (a1...a1000) into a list ? Also, please not that `df`, as you have defined it, is a vector of characters not a data.frame...

Comment: No- I cannot store the 1,000 data frames as the list. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you post the str(a1) results?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to combine them as List.( I do not know whether it is work with 1000 dataframe or not. )

```
df=c("John","Smith", .... "Machine")

list_object_names = sprintf("a%s", 1:1000)
list_df = lapply(list_object_names, get)

for (i in 1:length(list_df) ){

    list_df[[i]][,'Names']=df[i]
}
```

Also you can try apply function rather than for loop something like:

```
lapply(list_df, function(df) {
    #what you want to do
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In fact, I cannot create the "list". My question is simply how to create the "codes" rather than organize data frame and the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shot at this, without knowing if there is any more to the a1,a2...a1000 lists.

```
# generate your data
df = c("John", "Smith", "Machine")

# build your example
for(i in 1:3){ 
  assign(paste0("a",i), list(name = "XXXX")) 
}

# solve your problem, even if there is more to a1 than you are showing us. 
for(i in 1:3){
  anew <- get(paste0("a",i)) # pulls the object form the environment
  anew[['name']] <- df[i] # rewrites only that list
  assign(paste0("a",i), anew) # rewrites the object with new name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In fact, I cannot create the "list". My question is simply how to create the "codes" rather than organize data frame and the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am confused. I am creating the output you desire.

Comment: ? What do you mean create the codes? I assign the names into the code spot above